# Tracing an error in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, stack, trace

First time posting a question so I hope I do this right.  The main problem is that I cannot trace the error created when opening a form and would like advice on how to find the code triggering the problem.  I'm pasting the error below all this.  Unfortunately this isn't the error that points to a specific line of code so I feel stuck.

I also may need provide more background on this.  I recently received a new computer and have been getting all my applications reinstalled.  When I opened the project behind my web site (which is running fine) and ran it I received an error that told me the variable name could not contain spaces.  OK fine, I fixed it with brackets but then wondered why this is the first time I saw this error.  I pulled up the version of code that is running and found that the variable name is not bracketed.  Very strange, so I guess one side question would be why this is.  Here are the versions I have in the event it is relevant:

*Microsoft Visual Studio 2010
Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel
Installed Version: Professional*

Below is the error I receive.  Since this isn't one that I can step through (as far as I know) I would simply like to learn how to go about finding this.  Would be great if I understood why this wasn't a problem before, since I haven't changed anything yet!

> *Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding
>   the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the
>   exception stack trace below.   Stack Trace:  [FormatException: Input
>   string was not in a correct format.]
>   System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   +9591147    System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119
>   System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
>   +46    System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, TypeCode typeCode, IFormatProvider provider) +297
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, String
>   defaultValue, TypeCode type, Boolean convertEmptyStringToNull, Boolean
>   ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +126
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.GetValue(Object value, Boolean
>   ignoreNullableTypeChanges) +63
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter.get_ParameterValue() +40
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCollection.GetValues(HttpContext
>   context, Control control) +261
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.InitializeParameters(DbCommand
>   command, ParameterCollection parameters, IDictionary exclusionList)
>   +266    System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +653
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.PerformSelect() +38
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
>   Telerik.Web.UI.GridTableView.DataBind() +375
>   Telerik.Web.UI.RadGrid.DataBind() +173
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()
>   +75    System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102    System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2496*

Thanks for any guidance you might be able to provide

Dana

Comment: Based on the stack trace, it looks like you're not even using any code in this part of the system.  It looks like you're using the declarative data sources and binding directly to those.  Possibly an error with the markup for the data binding?  Could likely be unexpected data (a non-integer value where an integer value is expected, even in just one record).  It's clearly an error when trying to parse an integer from a non-integer value (usually a string).  But you'll need to find that run-time value in the data.

Comment: If you haven't changed anything in the code, the change would probably be in the new computer. Or to be more precise, in the installed OS and software versions. I presume the website that is running fine isn't running on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

You couldn't hit this line because it's not your code. It didn't break in the markup because it was *syntactically* correct. It broke further down the line because the code was *semantically* incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem causing the error.  Turns out I did change something on one of the dropdowns and hadn't realized.  Took my quite a while of commenting out code until I could isolate the problem.

Thanks to the helpful replies.

I'm still wondering why it was unable to point to the line causing the problem in the markup, like it does for the code-behind.  No way to do that?